# Elasticsearch Percentile calculation fetching wrong results

Tags: elasticsearch, percentile

Below is the data on which i am running the percentile aggregation from Elastic search

```
{ "index" :{}}
{"COORDINATES": "62.359006,08.90156267", "COUNTY": "TN","string": "", "long": 1552, "float": null, "date": "2019-01-30 00:00:00", "integer": 652, "double": 100005.03, "customerCode": "TenantC"}
{ "index" :{}}
{"COORDINATES": "99.359006,31.90156267", "COUNTY": "IL","string": "string P", "long": 1549, "float": 9999.07, "date": "2019-10-16 11:32:38", "integer": 978, "double": 300005.00, "customerCode": "TenantC"}
{ "index" :{}}
{"COORDINATES": "77.359006,13.90156267", "COUNTY": "TN","string": "string R", "long": 1234, "float": 43256.07, "date": "2019-10-16 11:32:38", "integer": 978, "double": 300005.00, "customerCode": "TenantC"}
{ "index" :{}}
{"COORDINATES": "66.359006,87.90156267", "COUNTY": "TN","string": "string S", "long": 1290, "float": 123478.69, "date": "2019-10-16 11:32:38", "integer": 978, "double": 400005.00, "customerCode": "TenantC"}
{ "index" :{}}
{"COORDINATES": "33.359006,78.90156267", "COUNTY": "TN","string": "string R", "long": 1345, "float": 34789.97, "date": "2019-10-16 11:05:38", "integer": 978, "double": 300005.00, "customerCode": "TenantC"}
{ "index" :{}}
{"COORDINATES": "14.359006,12.90156267", "COUNTY": "TN","string": "string R", "long": 1222, "float": 1008.07, "date": "2019-10-16 11:32:38", "integer": 978, "double": 300005.00, "customerCode": "TenantC"}
{ "index" :{}}
{"COORDINATES": "24.97556,40.36639449", "COUNTY": "PA","string": "string 84", "long": 1083, "float": 1000.84, "date": "2017-09-22 00:00:00", "integer": 183, "double": 99995.84, "customerCode": "TenantC"}
{ "index" :{}}
{"COORDINATES": "34.97556,29.36639449", "COUNTY": "PA","string": "string 82", "long": 1081, "float": 1000.82, "date": "2017-09-24 00:00:00", "integer": 181, "double": 99995.82, "customerCode": "TenantC"}
{ "index" :{}}
{"COORDINATES": "-80.97556,33.36639449", "COUNTY": "PA","string": "string 80", "long": 1079, "float": 1000.80, "date": "2017-09-26 00:00:00", "integer": 179, "double": 99995.80, "customerCode": "TenantC"}
{ "index" :{}}
{"COORDINATES": "2.97556,25.36639449", "COUNTY": "PA","string": "string 78", "long": 1077, "float": 1000.78, "date": "2017-09-28 00:00:00", "integer": 177, "double": 99995.78, "customerCode": "TenantC"}
{ "index" :{}}
{"COORDINATES": "-10.97556,50.36639449", "COUNTY": "PA","string": "string 76", "long": 1075, "float": 1000.76, "date": "2017-09-30 00:00:00", "integer": 175, "double": 99995.76, "customerCode": "TenantC"}
{ "index" :{}}
{"COORDINATES": "14.97556,60.36639449", "COUNTY": "PA","string": "string 74", "long": 1073, "float": 1000.74, "date": "2017-10-02 00:00:00", "integer": 173, "double": 99995.74, "customerCode": "TenantC"}
{ "index" :{}}
{"COORDINATES": "-14.97556,20.36639449", "COUNTY": "PA","string": "string 72", "long": 1071, "float": 1000.72, "date": "2017-10-04 00:00:00", "integer": 171, "double": 99995.72, "customerCode": "TenantC"}
{ "index" :{}}
{"COORDINATES": "44.97556,60.36639449", "COUNTY": "PA","string": "string 70", "long": 1069, "float": 1000.70, "date": "2017-10-06 00:00:00", "integer": 169, "double": 99995.70, "customerCode": "TenantC"}
{ "index" :{}}
{"COORDINATES": "-74.97556,44.36639449", "COUNTY": "PA","string": "string 68", "long": 1067, "float": 1000.68, "date": "2017-10-08 00:00:00", "integer": 167, "double": 99995.68, "customerCode": "TenantC"}
{ "index" :{}}
{"COORDINATES": "44.914506,12.844442", "COUNTY": "TX","string": "string 66", "long": 1065, "float": 1000.66, "date": "2017-10-10 00:00:00", "integer": 165, "double": 99995.66, "customerCode": "TenantC"}
{ "index" :{}}
{"COORDINATES": "76.914506,70.844442", "COUNTY": "TX","string": "string 64", "long": 1063, "float": 1000.64, "date": "2017-10-12 00:00:00", "integer": 163, "double": 99995.64, "customerCode": "TenantC"}
{ "index" :{}}
{"COORDINATES": "26.914506,40.844442", "COUNTY": "TX","string": "string 60", "long": 1059, "float": 1000.60, "date": "2017-10-16 00:00:00", "integer": 159, "double": 99995.60, "customerCode": "TenantC"}
{ "index" :{}}
{"COORDINATES": "-18.914506,22.844442", "COUNTY": "TX","string": "string 58", "long": 1057, "float": 1000.58, "date": "2017-10-18 00:00:00", "integer": 157, "double": 99995.58, "customerCode": "TenantC"}
{ "index" :{}}
{"COORDINATES": "56.914506,40.844442", "COUNTY": "TX","string": "string 56", "long": 1055, "float": 1000.56, "date": "2017-10-20 00:00:00", "integer": 155, "double": 99995.56, "customerCode": "TenantC"}
{ "index" :{}}
{"COORDINATES": "-45.914506,42.844442", "COUNTY": "TX","string": "string 54", "long": 1053, "float": 1000.54, "date": "2017-10-22 00:00:00", "integer": 153, "double": 99995.54, "customerCode": "TenantC"}
{ "index" :{}}
{"COORDINATES": "-86.914506,22.844442", "COUNTY": "TX","string": "string 52", "long": 1051, "float": 1000.52, "date": "2017-10-24 00:00:00", "integer": 151, "double": 99995.52, "customerCode": "TenantC"}
{ "index" :{}}
{"COORDINATES": "86.914506,64.844442", "COUNTY": "TX","string": "string 62", "long": 1061, "float": 1000.62, "date": "2017-10-14 00:00:00", "integer": 161, "double": 99995.62, "customerCode": "TenantC"}
```

> > And below is the ES Query for fetching the third_percentile (75.0th percentile).

```
{
"from": 0,
"size": 0,
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "bool": {
                    "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                    "boost": 1.0
                }
            }
        ],
        "adjust_pure_negative": true,
        "boost": 1.0
    }
},
"aggregations": {
    "integer": {
        "percentiles": {
            "field": "double",
            "percents": [
                75.0
            ],
            "missing": 300005.00,
            "keyed": true
        }
    }
}
```

}

> The response i get is as below :

```
{
"took": 4,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": {
        "value": 23,
        "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
},
"aggregations": {
    "integer": {
        "values": {
            "75.0": 100002.73249999998
        }
    }
}
```

}

The response value 100002.73249999998 is not present in my index data at all. I believe i should get is 100005.03

Please help me what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Percentile calculations in ElasticSearch are approximate , [refer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-percentile-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-metrics-percentile-aggregation-approximation) this link for details. In summary , for large number of documents the default counting/aggregation algorithms for these calculations will not scale

Comment: Yeah that's right. But the data i have it here is having just 23 rows and not much. I could see only problem with third_quartile (75.0 percentile) calculation.